# PHP call of undefined function hash_equals()

Tags: php, mysql

any one can help me out of this problem?
i'm getting error of  '`call of undefined function hash_equals()`'
here is my code:

```
$username = 'Admin';
$password = 'sample1Pasword';

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $USER, $PASSWORD);

$sth = $dbh->prepare('
  SELECT
    hash
  FROM users
  WHERE
    username = :username
  LIMIT 1
  ');

$sth->bindParam(':username', $username);

$sth->execute();

$user = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

// Hashing the password with its hash as the salt returns the same hash
if ( hash_equals($user->hash, crypt($password, $user->hash)) ) {
  // Ok!
}else{
  //user not found
}
```

I dont know what's going on, i just search for this function but it givin me a problem instead.
sorry for my bad english. Thank you!

Comment: What is your php version?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php) docs we can find a replacement function for older php versions :

```
if(!function_exists('hash_equals'))
{
    function hash_equals($str1, $str2)
    {
        if(strlen($str1) != strlen($str2))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $res = $str1 ^ $str2;
            $ret = 0;
            for($i = strlen($res) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--)
            {
                $ret |= ord($res[$i]);
            }
            return !$ret;
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you could use this library : https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Comment: `hash_equals` is not present in [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: Is this kinda 'safe' to use please?

Comment: yes its is safe and password_compat is a replacement method

Answer (score 9):

From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php):

> (PHP 5 >= 5.6.0)

If you have a version older than 5.6.0 then you will not have this function built-in.

Answer (score 1):

Use `phpinfo()` and check your PHP version. PHP versions prior to 5.6 don't have `hash_equals` function built-in. Upgrade to the latest version of PHP (or at least to 5.6) to use this function.

Answer (score 1):

Solution taken from Facebook sdk:
 https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/blob/5.x/src/Facebook/polyfills.php

```
/**
 * Copyright 2017 Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * You are hereby granted a non-exclusive, worldwide, royalty-free license to
 * use, copy, modify, and distribute this software in source code or binary
 * form for use in connection with the web services and APIs provided by
 * Facebook.
 *
 * As with any software that integrates with the Facebook platform, your use
 * of this software is subject to the Facebook Developer Principles and
 * Policies [http://developers.facebook.com/policy/]. This copyright notice
 * shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL
 * THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
 * FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
 * DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 *
 */
/**
 * @see https://github.com/sarciszewski/php-future/blob/master/src/Security.php#L37-L51
 */
if (!function_exists('hash_equals')) {
    function hash_equals($knownString, $userString)
    {
        if (function_exists('mb_strlen')) {
            $kLen = mb_strlen($knownString, '8bit');
            $uLen = mb_strlen($userString, '8bit');
        } else {
            $kLen = strlen($knownString);
            $uLen = strlen($userString);
        }
        if ($kLen !== $uLen) {
            return false;
        }
        $result = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $kLen; $i++) {
            $result |= (ord($knownString[$i]) ^ ord($userString[$i]));
        }
        // They are only identical strings if $result is exactly 0...
        return 0 === $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(!function_exists('hash_equals'))
{
    function hash_equals($a,$b){
        /***
        * special delay incrementing dos robust comparator
        */  
        $ip_one = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        $ip_two = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $db = new SQLdb();
        $counter = $db->quickquery("SELECT count(*) FROM dos WHERE (ip='".$ip_one."' OR ip='".$ip_two."') AND  recent_datetime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)");
        if ($counter > 5) {
            sleep($counter *2);
        }
        if ($a!=b){
            $db->quickquery("INSERT INTO dos (ip, recent_datetime) VALUES ('".$ip_one."', now())");
            $db->quickquery("INSERT INTO dos (ip, recent_datetime) VALUES ('".$ip_two."', now())");
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

This is probably better - you need a small table called dos with 2 columns (`ip text`, `recent_datetime datetime`) and you should DEFINITELY index `recent_datetime`. And add your own sql engine. I don't pre-prepare the mysql statements. It's legible and consider it pseudo code if you like. So calm down. You life will not end. I doubt very much you can inject the server ip address variables, and if you can Zend are muppets. Anyway I digress.

You will get a authentication hammer protection from this which is fairly ok.